# How can I make users able to edit a list's item using InfoPath?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, list, infopath, edit

I am a new user of SharePoint, and I am in the following situation:

I have users (from Group A) who create items in a list using an InfoPath form, indicating some columns of the item. Afterward, other users (from Group B) have to fill the leftovers.

I know that it can be simply done using the basic SharePoint interface. But I want something more user-friendly for Group B, using InfoPath like Group A for example.

But I spent my morning looking up for solutions on the internet, and did not find anything that helped me archive this.

Are there any ways to make Group B able to edit items created by Group A using InfoPath ? Or anything else, but that is user-friendly.

I am working on:
Office 365's SharePoint 2013, InfoPath 2013

Regards.

Comment: What kind of user-friendly form do you want? Could you please provide the detail? Users have edit permission on the item can edit it whether you are using the InfoPath form or OOB list form.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

By user friendly I mean I want Group B to be able to modify the list using InfoPath. But I struggle to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look into Content-Types:

Define 2 content types with the corresponding site columns:

A --> create an infopath form

B --> leave as is. and use the custom form.

Add both content-types to your list.
There can by only one content type active at time. So when group A wants to edit you have to change it to that content type (or visa versa) (it is a field in your list)